# When I install android-studio, I get this error

Tags: android-studio

error when installing android studio

ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\helloworld\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: uft-8
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\helloworld\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[1,39]
Message: Invalid encoding name "uft-8".
Affected Modules: app

[image]

Comment: It's just a typo on your part: WRONG: `"uft-8"`.  CORRECT: `"utf-8"`

Answer (score 0):

Check for this line at the top of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Your error is:

> ```
> ParseError at [row,col]:[1,39] Message: Invalid encoding name "uft-8". Affected Modules: app
>                                                                ^^^^^
> ```

See how `"utf-8"` and `"uft-8"` are different things.

Thus to resolve the problem just change the top line's `"uft-8"` to `"utf-8"`